# Implementing ILeaseManager for EventProcessorHost

Tags: .net, azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

On the project I am working on I DO NOT want to use Azure Storage to manage my offsets and checkpoints and plan to use a database approach to store them instead. I am using EventProcessor to read events from an event hub and I understand I can create my own implementations of `ILeaseManager` and `ICheckpointManager` to achieve this. I have a good understanding of how ICheckpointManager  works but I can not find any useful guidelines to help with a custom implementation of ILeaseManager. In fact I only need the minimal implementation of ILeaseManager because I am working with only one partition for now. When I run my application I get an error because the CreateLeaseIfNotExistAsync is not implemented and I do not know how to implement it as per this question.

Comment: You should consider using the new SDK instead. Here is the new one:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/

Answer (score 2):

In the official GitHub repo you find an example for an [in-memory StorageManager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/05d4890533e3a82eca759dadaa4984d1aba936bd/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Shared/src/Testing/InMemoryStorageManager.cs), which implements [StorageManager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/7bc0d0fdaef92602064e1780743a80a14a531695/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Shared/src/Processor/StorageManager.cs) as an alternative to the BlobStorageManager. This should give you sufficient material do build you own.